# Elastic Beanstalk running on Amazon linux 2 is not loading .ebextensions configs

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, redis, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a spring boot application running on elastic beanstalk - Amazon linux 2 AMI

I want to install `redis` on my EC2 instance when the environment is created and also modify the EC2 security group

To install Redis, I have add a file - `redis.config` in `.ebextensions` folder which is at root level with the below content

```
commands:
    redis01:
       command: sudo amazon-linux-extras install redis6
    redis02:
       command: redis-server --daemonize yes
```

To change the EC2 `security group name`, I have added a file `securitygroup.config` with the below content

```
option_settings:
  - namespace: aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration
    option_name: SecurityGroups
    value: MySecurityGroup
```

But, when the environment is created none of these commands are running. What is going wrong here? Any leads on this will be much helpful. Thanks!

Comment: Did you check any EB logs to look for a possible errors?

Comment: I don't see any errors in `eb-engine.log`

`20:14:43.307001 [INFO] Executing instruction: PostBuildEbExtension
20:14:43.307030 [INFO] Starting executing the config set Infra-EmbeddedPostBuild.
20:14:43.633118 [INFO] Finished executing the config set Infra-EmbeddedPostBuild.
20:14:43.633143 [INFO] Executing instruction: CleanEbExtensions
20:14:43.633168 [INFO] Cleaned ebextensions subdirectories from app staging directory.`